# Pandas engine parameter

Tags: pandas

While reading the Pandas API documentation in the read_excel section, I noticed that there is an engine parameter that lists odf as an option.

Does this mean that read_excel can now read a spreadsheet directly from OpenOffice or LibreOffice?

If the answer is yes, is there any extra setup required besides just specifying 'engine:odf'?

Answer (score 0):

The `engine` keyword, in `read_excel`, is meant to provide, `pandas`, information about which underlying (python) package should, be used for the operation.

Practically, this means, you should install the corresponding package for the engine (see table below).

```
| ENGINE   | Python Package |
|----------|----------------|
| xlrd     | xlrd           |
| openpyxl | openpyxl       |
| odf      | odfpy          |
```

Pandas is responsible for providing a common platform, where you can **invoke** functionality of the underlying package with, `dataframe` data as input for the operations (reading, writting, formatting etc.)

So, when if you are planning to use `engine=odf`, you have to install `odfpy` and how any of the *acutal work* is done, depends on `odfpy` implementation.